# how to specify table name in addColumn() function in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to get values from a `table` but don't know where to specify `table` name in `addColumn()` function in `magento`. Kindly help.
 Following is the code:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(


    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Orders'),

    'index'     => 'orders_count',

    'type'      => 'number',

    'total'     => 'sum',

    'sortable'  => false

    ));


}
```

Comment: please add more code to this

Comment: please add more code and specify for what task you are writing this code

Comment: i am writing this code since i want to retrieve data from a table. The column names to be retrieved are written in addColumn() function but i don't know which part of the code specifies the table name.

Comment: from which table you want to retrieve data tell i will help you out

Comment: sales_flat_order_item is the name of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It looks like your Grid code

Whenever Grid is loading firstly it will load a function "_prepareCollection()" where we collect collection data to show in grid. There we define our resource model(or table).

Example:

protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('module/table_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Comment: please upgrade the answer by clicking up arrow if answer is useful for you and accept it if this answer is fully satisfying your question.